# multiplying numbers in a string

Tags: python, multiplication

I'm doing some python in class, i have a test coming up but im struggling with somethings, i have some code here:

Now i have this, but i want to multiply the seven numbers they have just inputted in a specific order, For example:

```
num = str(input("Please enter 7 numbers"))
length = len(num)
while length < 7 or length > 7:
    num = input("Enter 7 numbers")
```

The numbers they inputted was 1234567 i would want to times every even index number by 3 and every odd one by 1, now ive tried this in a for loop such as:

`for t in range(1,7,2)`

but i didnt know what to do next, any methods would help or how to get this one to work.

Thanks Brad

Comment: I suggest that you fix the syntax errors before posting your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
string = ''
for t in range(1,8):
    if t % 2 == 0:                   # if t is even multiply t by 3 and add t to the string
        string += str(t * 3) + ' '
    else:                            # if t is odd simply add t to the string
        string += str(t) + ' '

print(string)
```

Ouptut:

```
1 6 3 12 5 18 7
```

I added a space after each number simply makes the output easier to read. If you want you could remove the `+ ' '` in the code to get this output:

```
163125187
```

Comment: Great that helped, But know i need to check its valid, and for that i need to add all them up and take it away from the nearest 10 any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean take it away from the nearest 10? Do you mean rounding up or rounding down?